# How can I write a function that, given a pointer to a map, returns a pointer to a specific element in the map?

Tags: c++, pointers, hashmap

I have a map:

```
std::map<int,float> m1;
```

I want to pass a pointer to that map to a function that will iterate over the map and return a pointer to a particular element in that map based on some condition.

```
float *foo(map<int,float> *m1){
  float *result;
  for(map<int,float>::iterator it = m1->begin(); it != m1->end(); it++)
    {
      if (condition)
        {
          result = &(it->second);
          break;
        }
    }
  return result;
}
```

This code did not compile. I'm having trouble seeing what is a pointer and what isn't. Also how does passing a pointer to the map affect the iterator loop ?

Thanks!

Comment: consider passing the map by const reference instead of by pointer

Comment: This code will return a wild pointer if `condition` is never satisfied since `result` is not initialized.

Comment: You _think_ this code will not work? So you didn't actually _try_ it?

Comment: Well, it did not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't write your own function, use the standard library : `std::find_if` is what you are looking for :

```
auto it = std::find_if (m1.begin(), m1.end(), TestFunction);
if(it != m1.end())
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The iterator (ite) is a stack variable and and you returns a pointer to a variable in the stack (&ite->second). This is wrong.

Comment: Normally it would be, but `iterator->second` gives a reference to the actual `float` in the map, so in this case things would actually work. At least until the map reorganizes itself in memory.

Comment: @dlf: "until the map reorganizes itself in memory" - that won't happen. A reference to a map element is only invalidated when the element is removed from the map.